# What is the best method to connect to a database in php?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am relatively new to php and I need to connect to a database using php, as i understand there are several methods of connecting to a database, what is the most current method of doing this?

Comment: What flavour of database? Then use the appropriate adapter which probably has a `connect()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use built-in PHP methods, I would advise using PHP PDO. You can find more information on PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). You can also use a separate package to manage connections for you such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), though this can get a little more complex in the setup. If you are just getting started in PHP, it may be easier to start off with PDO. I hope this helps!